# Binary representation of the inverse of a big integer

Tags: type-conversion, python-3.5, division, integer-division

For cryptographic purposes, I have to write the binary representation of the inverse of a big number *p*, whose size is roughly 16k bits. But I couldn't find any library allowing to convert such an integer to a float (I'm working on C/Python). Especially, as the inverse 1/*p* is extremely small, I've tried to shift the binary representation by dividing instead the closest power of ten smaller than *p*, by *p*, but the problem remains as I can't convert *p* to perfom the division.

Does there exist some algorithms computing this kind of inversion? Do I have to implement them or are they already present in some libraries? I am working with python3.5.

Comment: Have you looked at [The GNU MPFR Library](https://www.mpfr.org). There is a nice wrapper of this library in R called [Rmpfr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/Rmpfr.pdf)